# I have to create one Toolbar for each activity in my Android app?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have this doubt about new Toolbar in Android.

I have to create one Toolbar for each activity in my app or there are a best practice to create one Toolbar for all activities?

I try create a Singleton inflating a layout and search a view ID to create a toolbar and return the same instance for all activities, but this don't work.

Can anybody help me? :S

Answer (score 29):

`Toolbar` is just a view and you have to add it to your each `Activity` in which you want to show it.

One way is to just put it in a separate layout file and include in your `Activity` layout.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now in your Activity layout where you want to add it just include like this:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Comment: @DanielFilho you can accept it as Answer if it works for your.

Comment: @Sharj I need to set the Id for every include?

Comment: Yes, you do, if you want to access it in Java code.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to use the Id for every include. You only need to set it up in its layout and then include it in other activities

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend Your activity class with `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Just some code with no explanation isn't very helpful.  Where does this code go?  How do you access this code from your Activities?  etc.