# Android toolbar to all the activities

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I need to define the tool bar to all the activity. For home screen I have some menu icons on toolbar.

For other activities I need to have back button on toolbar with some selected menu icons. (visible true and false).

What's the best approach ?

1. Define one toolbar and user it everywhere
2. Create toolbar every time for each activities.

When I create new activities I don't want to create toolbar every time. What's the best way to have activities in inheritance way. (define toolbar once and use it everywhere on activity screen)?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772989/i-have-to-create-one-toolbar-for-each-activity-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a layout named toobar.xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          />
```

Then include this in every activity layout file:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Then initiate in onCreate() of every activity:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Create theme to remove default ActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

Set theme in manifest:

```
   <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: then I need  to instantiate the toolbar in every activities onCreate method ?

Comment: Yes you do have to do that

Comment: Yes, just set toolbar as SupportActionBar in every activity. And set theme of your activities as above.

Answer (score 2):

Create a toolbar and use it with fragments, it's the easiest method

Comment: any examples of how I can use it with fragments ? Thanks

Comment: Yes! In the Toolbar Activity set a `FrameLayout` and give it a ID. Rhen go to your Java path and create new -> Fragment -> Fragment(Blank). 

You need to create the respective layout for the fragment.

Then, for calling the fragment set something like:

`fragmentname fragmentname = new fragmentname();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentlayout, fragmentname, fragmentname.getTag()).commit();`

Comment: And everytime you want to call another fragment like you was supposed to do with the Activities, create a new fragment and call it with this method

Answer (score 0):

You can use BaseActivity pattern. With it you can define toolbar in base and extend that in all other activities. or you can change fragments at bottom part of toolbar using frame layout.

Answer (score 0):

tahsinRupam, I had to to 
change: `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`
to: `<include android:layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`