# Have trouble setting up Toolbar in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, toolbar

I am new to android development, (Rather of a PHP background) and tried adding a toolbar to an app I am building. The toolbar works but requires me to initialize it in every activity! Surely there must be a better way than that? I tried creating another class SetupActivity extending AppCompactActivity and moved all the repeated code in there. But no activity calls the onCreate in SetupActivity.
Then I tried using a fragment but it is not a subclass of Context.
Please help me find a way to fix it. Thanks!

Edit: I have to use the `setSupportActionBar` in every activity before I can get it to display.

Also, The app bar has a button that sends the user to another activity. I have to create the button using Java and then add a click listener to it in every activity.

Comment: Can you describe "require to initialize it' more specifically? Initialize it with what? Or maybe you want to display a toolbar and it is not visible? Add some activity code and styles/theme.xml code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android toolbar to all the activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760406/android-toolbar-to-all-the-activities)

Comment: Well I guess I will just combine some OOPS concepts myself. Seems like no one has trouble with it.

Comment: and no @DrHowdyDoo, this does not answer my question. I said that I tried Inheritance and fragments and none worked.

Comment: "fragment but it is not a subclass of Context" - what problem are u facing in fragments ? it it because u can't use any fucntion that require context ?

Comment: yes that's the trouble. I can't use setSupprtActionBar() from a fragment

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is through xml:-
What you can do is first create a style in your app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml file.
In the following example, I'm removing the action bar from my app
Eg:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then set this theme as the "android:theme" in the "application" tag of your app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file. Eg:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>
```

This way the style which you have created (containing the new toolbar) will be applied across your entire application.